# view error with Navigation controller thats inside another Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have added a navigation controller inside a viewcontroller thats inside another navigation controller... lol

well anyway because of this structure I have an issue with any views I push to the "sub"navigation controller.. because its only fitting inside the grame of the "parent" navigation controller its pushing the pushed views contents down by about 20/40pxl...

I was wondering how I get stop this from happening.. here are two pictures showing you what is happening.

[image]

where the label is clearly centered in Interface builder

[image]

This is the code I have so far for this stuff.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Init the (sub)navigationController
    otherNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    // Add this (sub)NavController to the current viewcontroller (which is inside the (parent)navcontroller)
    [self.view addSubview:otherNav.view];
    // Hide the (sub)NavControllerbar
    otherNav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    // Load a detial view into the (sub)NavController
    DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [otherNav pushViewController:detailView animated:NO];
}
```

The otherNav is also set up in the .h file for global access in this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "super" NavigationBar is visible, the self.view.frame.height is:

> - 480-20-44 (actualViewheight-statusbarheight-navigationBarheight).

There are 2 solutions for your problem.

### 1. For simplicity I would say, if your only problem is to make it centralized.

```
    [self.view addSubview:otherNav.view];
    [otherNav.view setCenter:self.view.center];
```

This will make your label center alligned.

### 2.Though, if you are using interface builder;

> 1. select the xib file.
> 2. select the view.
> 3. open Utilities.
> 4. set the Top bar as Navigation bar.

then the things you will align you will get as it is on device/simulator or what ever you are testing on.